# How to remember the pasted-called `url` after authentication in angular UI-Router?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

In my application, a person can just copying and pasting this URL:

```
https://autosuggest.com/fsHardSoft/createCase?sn=FOC0948Y1WB
```

When without `oAuth` requires the `authentication` user re-directed to `login` page. so user can give their credientials. once that success, how can i redirect them back to the URL what they tryied to visit. for your case :

```
( https://autosuggest.com/fsHardSoft/createCase?sn=FOC0948Y1WB)
```

Note: for authentication I am using `oAuth` token generator, which is controlled by other domain.

Thanks in advance.